# Electrical wiring methods , Acceptable or Not-Acceptable

Tags: electrical, wiring

I came across newer Residential Remodel, in Southern California, where All work is alleged to have been properly Permitted by local jurisdiction" including electrical-system wiring for garage-door opener and a bathroom' s ventilation fan that backs into an interior' s hallway closet, see pics.  My question is the wiring' s type and / or wiring method are acceptable or done in accordance to common construction practice?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above 8’ the Romex or nmb can be exposed , the only thing I see not 100% is the staple with the wire sideways.  It could be 14-3 and round wire but the other pieces look flat so other than that it would meet minimum code but not a nice job that’s for sure. You don’t show the cable going in the garage door opener or light if there are clamps that would be the only thing left to check. We can’t see if there is a nail plate in that notched ceiling joist maybe that could be a violation where the wire goes in between or is it just going through the Sheetrock then it would be ok. The fan box ?
Edit
The Romex should be nailed within 12” but I think my early thought about a nail plate may be wrong as it goes through the ceiling and someone put mudd over it. If it was stapled there it may have been ok.